# Can't locate and capture few fields out of some unstructured html

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scoop out four fields from a [webpage](http://www.nyeca.org/find-a-contractor-by-name/) using BeautifulSoup library. It's hard to identify the fields individually and that is the reason I seek help.

Sometimes both emails are present but that is not always the case. I used indexing to capture the email for this example but surely this is the worst idea to go with. Moreover, with the following attempt I can only parse the caption of the email, not the email address.

I've tried with (minimum working example):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
  <p>
   <strong>
    Robert Romanoff
   </strong>
   <br/>
   146 West 29th Street, Suite 11W
   <br/>
   New York, New York 10001
   <br/>
   Telephone: (718) 527-1577
   <br/>
   Fax: (718) 276-8501
   <br/>
   Email:
   <a href="mailto:robert@absol.com">
    robert@absol.com
   </a>
   <br/>
   Additional Contact: William Locantro
   <br/>
   Email:
   <a href="mailto:bill@absol.com">
    bill@absol.com
   </a>
  </p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
container = soup.select_one("p")
contact_name = container.strong.text.strip()
contact_email = [i for i in container.strings if "Email" in i][0].strip()
additional_contact = [i.strip() for i in container.strings if "Additional Contact" in i.strip()][0].strip('Additional Contact:')
additional_email = [i for i in container.strings if "Email" in i][1].strip()
print(contact_name,contact_email,additional_contact,additional_email)
```

Current output:

```
Robert Romanoff Email: William Locantro Email:
```

Expected output:

```
Robert Romanoff robert@absol.com William Locantro bill@absol.com
```

Comment: Could you share the URL. It is tough to give a solution that works for all cases.

Comment: Check out the edit @Ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complex html/xml parsing you should take a look at `xpath` which allows very powerful selector rules.

In python it's available in `parsel` package.

```
from parsel import Selector

html = '...'
sel = Selector(html)
name = sel.xpath('//strong[1]/text()').get().strip()
email = sel.xpath("//text()[re:test(., 'Email')]/following-sibling::a/text()").get().strip()
name_additional = sel.xpath("//text()[re:test(., 'Additional Contact')]").re("Additional Contact: (.+)")[0]
email_additional = sel.xpath("//text()[re:test(., 'Additional Contact')]/following-sibling::a/text()").get().strip()
print(name, email, name_additional, email_additional)
# Robert Romanoff robert@absol.com William Locantro bill@absol.com
```

Comment: I was mesmerized by your answer, so I forgot to ask what `re:test()` is doing here. Thanks.

Comment: `re:test` is an xpath function that performs regular expression match test on target. The function signature  is `re:test(target, pattern, flags)`. In this case we test `.` which refers to "self" (the text node) and our pattern is `"Additional Contact"` and we don't provide any flags (alternatively you could specify `"i"` to ignore case for example). Another way of doing the same function would be to use `contains()` function: `[contains(., "Additional Contact")]` - `re:test()` is just a more advanced version of this.

Comment: more on this on `parsel` docs: https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=re%3Atest#regular-expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

- Select the `<div>` that has the data you need.
- Create a list of the data present inside the above selected `<div>`
- Iterate over the list and extract the data you require.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.nyeca.org/find-a-contractor-by-name/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

d = soup.find_all('div', class_='sabai-directory-body')
for i in d:
    x = i.text.strip().split('\n')
    data = [x[0].strip()]
    for item in x:
        if item.startswith('Email'):
            data.append(item.split(':')[1].strip())
        elif item.startswith('Additional'):
            data.append(item.split(':')[1].strip())
    print(data)
```

Gives a list of the contractor details and also additional details (if any).

```
['Ron Singh', 'rsingh@atechelectric.com']
['George Pacacha', 'Office@agvelectricalservices.com']
['Andrew Drazic', 'ADrazic@atjelectrical.com']
['Albert Barbato', 'Abarbato@abelectriccorp.com']
['Ralph Sica', 'Ralph.Sica@abm.com', 'Henry Kissinger', 'Henry.Kissinger@abm.com']
['Robert Romanoff', 'robert@absoluteelectric.com', 'William Locantro', 'bill@absoluteelectric.com']
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can give it a try,

```
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

names_ = [
    soup.select_one("p > strong").text.strip(),
    soup.find(text=re.compile("Additional Contact:")).replace('Additional Contact:', '').strip()
]

email_ = [i.strip() for i in soup.find_all(text=re.compile("absol"))]

print(" ".join(i + " " + j for i, j in zip(names_, email_)))
```

---

```
Robert Romanoff robert@absol.com William Locantro bill@absol.com
```